# How do I migrate email data from Outlook Public Folders into SharePoint?

Tags: 2010, migration, email, outlook

I have a bunch of emails stored in different folders in Outlook Public Folders.  Each of these folders equates to new sites that will be made in SharePoint site collections (project folders become project sites, team folders become team sites, etc.).  We plan on having the users move their emails to the correct locations once we have the sites set up for them.

What is the best way to allow the users to move their emails from Outlook Public Folders into their respective SharePoint sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [great article](http://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/five-out-of-the-box-ways-to-get-email-into-sharepoint/) which details 5 different ways to move email into SharePoint.  The best method for me was to set up discussion board lists that the users could connect to their Outlook and then directly drop the emails into the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this article http://searchexchange.techtarget.com/tip/Manually-move-Exchange-public-folder-data-to-SharePoint  and I would recommend this Migrator for Documents tool ( http://www.lepide.com/lepidemigratordocuments/ ) which successfully migrate email data from outlook public folders to SharePoint Server.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. Please remember that answers containing only links to solutions are not recommended as link targets tend to disappear. Please elaborate you suggested answer inside the post. Feel free to include links to source articles as well.